# Javascript Logical AND (&&) operator behavior not working in WSO2 EI 6.6.0 Script mediator

Tags: javascript, wso2, logical-operators, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am just performing simple Logical AND Operation inside Script mediator of WSO2 EI 6.6.0

Code:

```
 <script language="js"><![CDATA[
 var log = mc.getServiceLog();   
var initial_group="L1";
var initial_queue ="";
 if( (initial_group =="L1") && (initial_queue ="WIN")){
     log.info("Matching success!");}
     else{
         log.info("Matching failed!");
     }
     ]]></script>
```

Even though i passed   `initial_queue`  as empty, `&&` condition of `if` statement is matched and finally it produce output like below

```
Matching success!
```

Instead of `Matching failed!`

Can anyone explain this strange behavior of Logical `&&` Operator?

Comment: It's probably a typo, you want `==` or `===` in `initial_queue ="WIN"`. In JavaScript, `=` is always **assignment**. For equality, use `==` or `===`.

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder

Thanks for your quick response. as you said it is typo. after replacing "=" as "==" works fine.